# Re-homing a Sites URL

Tags: blacktab, force.com-sites

Is it possible to move the Sites URL (e.g. mysiteurl.force.com) from one org to another? I know the UI says it's not possible to change Sites URLs, but it seems like something that support could do.

To clarify, all I wish to do is disable Sites in one org and move the URL mapping previously used for Sites there (e.g. mysiteurl.force.com) to another org. Both orgs are EE.

Before I submit a case to request it, I was hoping someone here could say if it's possible and what your experiences with it have been in the past.

Comment: you're on right track, salesforce support I believe can best help here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes you can. You can open up a support ticket in your current org and ask for the subdomain to be changed to something else which will then free up the one you want to be registered in your new org. I've successfully had Salesforce support modify my sites subdomain for me in orgs with no issue.

Comment: @jkraybill you should mark the question as answered if it answers your question.

Comment: Confirming that I've had them do this before as well without issue.

Comment: I'll jump in on the confirmation as well. And they can do it with a very quick turnaround.